# Rename SQLite table not working

Tags: sqlite, alter

I am using the following code (in B4A) to delete an old CUSTOMERS table and then rename a new version of it.  However, I always end up with a blank (new) CUSTOMERS table. If I don't do the rename the CUSTOMERS_NEW table is perfectly ok with the correct number of rows (1825).

```
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("DROP TABLE customers")                                     
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE newcustomers RENAME TO customers")
sqlobt.close
```

I am puzzled as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the table name `newcustomers` or `customers_new`?

Comment: The old table is customers and the new table is called newcustomers.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite can be quite particular with its table naming conventions. You could try:

```
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE 'newcustomers' RENAME TO 'customers'")
```

Additionally, you may need to sandwich your `ALTER TABLE` command with a `BEGIN`/`COMMIT TRANSACTION` command. Using `sqlite3`, your code may look something like this:

```
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("ALTER TABLE 'newcustomers' RENAME TO 'customers'")
sqlOBT.ExecNonQuery("COMMIT TRANSACTION")
```

In `python` I understand this to be the case since the `sqlite3` module automatically opens transactions in certain cases but not others. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).